# install older nvidia driver which has different subversion

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, nvidia

I'm not sure if subversion is the correct term.

I'm trying to set up a linux container with gpu pass through (ubuntu 16.04 host and container). the host has nvidia driver version 384.81 and if I try to install using `apt install nvidia-384` it will install 384.130 version which will result in nvidia-smi outputting error nvml version mismatch.

I tried downloading manually with wget for `384.81.deb` but after running `dpkg -i` there's no `nvidia-smi` command. I did purge and reboot between install so is there any way of installing the `384.81` in the container? or is it given that I have to update the host? its currently working properly for old containers so I don't want to break anything.